# Coping files from multiple sub folders using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Copy file from multiple sub-folder to another multiple sub-folder

example :

```
C:\Nani\Code\Relase4\database1\tables
C:\Nani\Code\Relase1\database1\tables
C:\Nani\Code\Relase2\database1\tables
C:\Nani\Code\Relase3\cycle1\database1\tables 
C:\Nani\Code\Relase1\database1.02.tables
```

I have .sql files in above all folders and i want to copy to

`C\Build\database1\tables`

if database1\tables directory is not there , i have to create it too ,

```
$sourceFolder  = "C:\Nani\Code"
$targetFolder  = "C\Build"
Get-Childitem $sourceFolder -recurse -filter "*.sql"  -Exclude $exclude | %{
    #If destination folder doesn't exist
    if (!(Test-Path $targetFolder -PathType Container)) {
    #Create destination folder
        New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory -Force
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $targetFolder -Recurse -force 
}
```

above code is not creating sub folders in destination ,

Comment: Because it is not going inside that condition itself. Also, I want to know what are the things that you are passing in the `Exclude` parameter.

Comment: $exclude ="*.cs" files ,can you please send script

Comment: You do not need to use the exclude if you are already filtering with *.sql . So, I have removed that part itself. I have posted an answer . Kindly modify the script accordingly.
Also robocopy can copy multiple source folders to a single destination and vice versa.Go through [ROBOCOPY USAGE](https://serverfault.com/questions/272919/copy-multiple-folders-to-a-single-destination-with-robocopy)

Answer (score 0):

I have kept the script very simple for your understanding and commented the sections.
Make sure you add all the validations for paths and error handling. Else if any of the files is giving any issue, then it wont proceed and will break the loop.

**Script:**

```
#Keeping all the sources in an array
$Sources = @("C:\Nani\Code\Relase4\database1\tables",
"C:\Nani\Code\Relase1\database1\tables",
"C:\Nani\Code\Relase2\database1\tables",
"C:\Nani\Code\Relase3\cycle1\database1\tables",
"C:\Nani\Code\Relase1\database1.02.tables")

$Destination="C\Build\database1\tables\"

#Iterating each source folder
foreach($source in $sources)
{
#Getting all the sql files under an iteration folder recursively 
$files=Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter "*.sql" -Recurse 

    #Iterating all the files underneath a single source folder
    foreach ($file in $files) 
    {
    #Copying the files for a single folder to the destination
    Copy-Item $file.PSPath -Destination  ("$Destination" + ($file.PSParentPath | Split-Path -Leaf) + '_' + $file)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Dutta ,
I have a source folder C:\Nani\Code , under this so many releases folders are there now i want to copy files to Build folder 
C\Build\database1\tables
Means i have a 10 release folders having database objects like above folder structure , now i have to copy all files to single build folder like database1\tables

Comment: Ya. Then pick only the files and move it to the destination. You do not need to maintain the hierarchy in the destination folder at all. Directly loop all the folders recrsively in a foreach and then pick all the files followed by a direct movement to the destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am creating each folder first before copying files into it.

```
$sourceFolder  = "C:\Nani\Code"
$targetFolder  = "C:\Build"
$sources = Get-Childitem $sourceFolder -recurse -filter "*.sql"  -Exclude $exclude | Select FullName, DirectoryName
foreach ($source in $sources)
{
    $Releasepath = [regex]::match($source.DirectoryName,'C:\\Nani\\Code\\Release\d').Value
    $split = $Releasepath.Replace("\","\\")
    $targetfolderLeaf = $source.DirectoryName -split $split | select -Last 1
    $targetfolderpath = $targetFolder+$targetfolderLeaf
    if (!(Test-Path $targetfolderpath -PathType Container)) {
    #Create destination folder
        New-Item -Path $targetfolderpath -ItemType Directory -Force
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $source.FullName -Destination $targetfolderpath -Recurse -force 
}
```

Comment: I have a source folder C:\Nani\Code , under this so many releases folders are there now i want to copy files to Build folder C\Build\database1\tables Means i have a 10 release folders having database objects like above folder structure , now i have to copy all files to single build folder like database1\tables

Comment: @Nani I have edited my answer. Hope it's "release" in path and not "relase". I think this should work, if not modify accordingly.

Comment: Please don't hard code path ,just take as last folder name from path create that folder in destination(so many folders having same folder in sub folders) , this is also good enough for me

Comment: @Nani Modify according to your requirement and mark answer as useful if this works for you.

Comment: Please don't hard code path ,just take as last folder name from path create that folder in destination(so many folders having same folder in sub folders)  i want like this , can you please send script